# RTC/Jazz How to give a Local Build?

Tags: eclipse, rtc, ibm-jazz

I would like to give a local build in RTC eclipse client of my files without affecting the remote repo.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like doing [personal builds](https://jazz.net/blog/index.php/2008/10/17/how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-personal-builds/comment-page-1/):

[image]

That way, you don't create baseline on the stream seen and share by everyone: the sources from that personal build are coming from your own workspace, instead of the stream.